# What is a TensorSpec? (Tensorflow 2.0)

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, python-3.x

what is a [tf.TensorSpec()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorSpec) and what is it used for?

Answer (score 2):

TensorSpec is mostly used by tf.function to specify input signature. tf.function will create a graph for different input shapes and datatypes, but it is possible that your function graph is compatible with different shapes. As a performance optimization, You can optionally provide a signature so that no unnecessary graphs are created.